# How to use lodash to deep set without creating undefined values

Tags: javascript, lodash

Given this example using [lodash](https://lodash.com/):

```
var object = {};
_.set(object, [ 1, 2 ], 5);
console.log(object);
```

The resultant object in the console is:

```
{
  1: [undefined, undefined, 5]
}
```

Now imagine, instead of the integer 2, you are setting a timestamp of 1445231475.  You now have 1445231474 undefined values in a very large array that will run out of memory after a few `_.set` operations.

If possible with `_.set`, how would one go about creating this object:

```
{
  1: {
    2: 5
  }
}
```

It is possible if 2 is truly a string like "a", but Lodash will force even "2" into the array of multiple undefined values.

I can use `_.merge` if necessary, but I would be more excited about using `_.set` capability.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can do this with lodash `setWith`

```
// unwanted behavior with set
let x = {}
_.set(x, [1,2], 'test')
// x = { '1': [ <2 empty items>, 'test' ] }

// desired behavior with setWith
let y = {}
_.setWith(y, [1,2], 'test', Object)
// y = { '1': { '2': 'test' } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, **no**, it's not possible to do that, and here's why:

Within [`_.set`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/3.10.1/lodash.src.js#L10155), this is the relevant part:

```
if (index == lastIndex) {
  nested[key] = value;
} else if (nested[key] == null) {
  nested[key] = isIndex(path[index + 1]) ? [] : {};
}
```

What happens here is that whenever a path item doesn't exist as a key, it is tested if it is a valid index (is of type `number`, or matches `/^\d+$/`) and if so an array is created, otherwise an object.

Because `key` is a string, and the goal is to set a property named ***2*** (or any other numerical value), it will always return true from `isIndex` and will results in an array.

Comment: Thanks @Amit, great description of 'why not'.  I now have an option for a custom mixin with similar properties to _.set, or a _.merge, which is probably the way I'll go.  Cheers!

Comment: @ryanm, can you elaborate? I'm running into a similar issue and want to avoid this 'feature' of _.set.

Comment: @Sigfried I'm out of the mindspace of this Q&A, but I'll try to help.  I think the key around this is using a string for the key `"3"` instead of `3`, or using an array (lodash collection).  There is also a customizer for setting you could override to assist with your custom need: https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#setWith  Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! Using a string doesn't work, but setWith does:  `_.set({}, 'foo.5', true)` produces `{"foo":[null,null,null,null,null,true]}`, which is no good, but `_.setWith({}, 'foo.5', true, Object)` produces `{"foo":{"5":true}}`.